# Creating a Decoder Target Sequence

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of integers in an array.

```
Input: sequencesInputDecode[0]
Output: [576, 5, 272, 15]
Input: sequencesInputDecode[5]
Output: [1462, 2, **1463**, 2, 1464]
Input: sequencesInputDecode[5][2]
Output: **1463**
```

And so on and forth.  Now I would like to transfer this entire array while removing the first element of each sequence.  Remove *576* from `sequencesInputDecode[0]`, Remove *1462* from `sequencesInputDecode[5]`

But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `sequencesInputDecode[0].remove(sequencesInputDecode[0][0])` This code will remove the first item `576` from `sequencesInputDecode[0]`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in an iterative manner?  I tried

`for i in range(len(sequencesTargetDecode)):
    sequencesTargetDecode[i].remove(sequencesTargetDecode[i][0])`

But I got error **list index out of range.**  Although I can manually do it:
sequencesTargetDecode[0].remove(sequencesTargetDecode[0][0])

Weird

Comment: Try going through the list backwards. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/backward-iteration-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes every first entry from all lists in your `sequenceInputDecode` list.

```
for seq in sequencesInputDecode:
    if seq: # check if seq is empty
        _ = seq.pop(0) # or: seq.remove(seq[0])
```

Comment: It says I am **popping from an empty list**.  I tried another way and it says **list index out of range.**  Which is weird because the list isn't empty when I checked

Comment: There is probably an empty list in your list of lists. You can add `if seq:` before `_ = seq.pop(0)` to check if it is empty and popping only if it is not.

Comment: What's the _ for? In  `_ = seq.pop(0)`.  I am really new to Python.

Comment: `list.pop(idx)` returns the element of `list` with index `idx`, if you omit the `_ = ` it will be printed to the command line. By using the underscore you suppress the output and assign it to some kind of 'garbage' variable. Alternative you can use `list.remove(list[0])` this really removes the entry without returning the object.